# Run a job with Spring @Scheduled annotation at two different times on different days of the week

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron

I have a job that has to be run

- at 8:00 on weekdays
- at 10:00 on weekends

My thinking is - Either

- the CRON expression has to handle both of it together so that it can be given inside the @Scheduled annotation
- Otherwise, a single @Scheduled annotation has to take in 2 CRON expression.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can write method and call it twice with `@Scheduled` annotation on both of them with different CRONs.

Comment: I agree with @ROHAN. It should work, you can test it on minimal intervals like minutes or seconds. The other way, with only one cron, I think is impossible

Comment: I want to know did you find any solution to this except the one I answered?

Comment: Yes @RohanShah . I have posted the answer. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Schedules` annotation can be used to set multiple calendar-based timer expressions.

> This annotation will get rid of the redundancy of writing the same
>   method multiple times.

In the following example, the first expression sets a timer to expire on the last day of every month. The second expression sets a timer to expire every Friday at 11:00 PM.

```
@Schedules ({
    @Schedule(dayOfMonth="Last"),
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek="Fri", hour="23")
})
public void doPeriodicCleanup() { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your method does exactly the same work then write it once and call it twice with two different CRONs.

```
public void doStuff(){
//do stuff
}

@Scheduled //With 8 AM Weekdays CRON
doStuff();

@Scheduled //With 10 AM Weekends CRON
doStuff();
```